# Does "bad credit" affect postdoc application in math?

Tags: job-search, postdocs

Does a bad credit score affect my chance in applying for a postdoc in math? In my case, I have a credit card that had the bill sent to the wrong address and this impacted my score with all three credit agencies.

Comment: Crosspost on money.stackexchange?

Comment: I've never heard of academic employers screening based upon credit scores. A bad credit score _might_ affect your ability to get a postdoc position that requires a security clearance (e.g., NSA or a DOE national lab).

Comment: Okay. I suggested edits to make your question more general. Also, where are you looking for a postdoc? Academia, gov't, private sector?

Comment: It could affect your chances if you mention it in the interview. It will show that you are irresponsible and absent-minded; if you are also bright this could help.

Comment: Be careful; some of the people answering do not have any experience with hiring for math postdocs. (For example, a comment above referenced interviews; but there are no interviews for math postdocs.)

Comment: @Tom Church: Each of the 3 finalists, of which I was one, for a math postdoc I applied to had a conference-phone interview with the hiring committee. But this was for the 1996-97 academic year, and maybe it's no longer done.

Comment: @TomChurch Oh yes; even in things I have experience I like to proceed from thought/understanding rather than inferring from experience.

Answer (score 4):

I have a lot of experience with postdoc hiring in mathematics at several institutions.  There is no mechanism by which faculty who are reading postdoc files would know your credit score, so you shouldn't worry that it will affect your application.

HR departments don't really play a role in academic job searches (aside from technical things like approving the wording of job ads).  It is all done by academics.  So though in the private sector HR departments do things like run credit searches, this just doesn't happen during faculty and postdoc searches at universities.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the position and organization you are applying to. Since it is in math, I would say no. Your employer will most likely not check your credit score/report. When I was in HR, I only ran credit checks for people who would have financial control over a certain department (i.e. CFO, budget officers, etc.). Since pulling credit reports/scores require explicit permission, it will be stated in either the job application or the recruiter will tell you - it might also be possible that it's listed on the job description - in which case you can either agree, or disagree to it.

Comment: What do you mean by "recruiter"? That's a common role in hiring in the private sector, but I've never heard of anyone with such a title being involved in academic hiring.

Comment: @NateEldredge In HR, anyone responsible for posting job descriptions and/or doing the initial resume review is known as a recruiter.